# Django Sites framework - can I do these things?

Tags: django, django-sites

I have a general idea of what the Sites framework is, but after much researching, I can't confirm if what *I'm* trying to achieve is possible.

Here's what I want to achieve (simplified). These would be three separate sites - and separate Django projects. Is this possible?

**Site/Project 1: Customers.ourdomain.com**

- This site manages everything about our customers.
- There would be a model called `Contact` which stores all the information about customers (name, address, email, etc.)
- Have views that a for viewing the `Contact` model objects, editing their details, etc

**Site/Project 2: WorkOrders.ourdomain.com**

- This site would manage all things pertaining to Work Orders
- there would be a `WorkOrder` model, to create/edit/manage work orders for doing installs and service, etc.
- In order to create work orders for our customers, the `WorkOrder` model would need to know about the `Customer` model from the other site. The work order site doesn't need to edit the customer's data - just needs to have *read access* of all the customers

**Site/Project 3: Accounting.ourdomain.com**

- Accounting site for handling all things accounting, such as invoices, accounts receivable, revenue, etc.
- There would be a bunch of accounting related models, like `Invoice`, `Payment`, etc.
- The Accounting site would need to know, and access (read only) all the records in *both* the Contact site (to know who to invoice) and all the Work Order models, to reference how much labour and materials was used to figure out the amount owing.

---

So there would be three separate sites each as a separate Django application, but some of the models would need to be visible to other other sites.

Is this possible?

---

We have some specific use-case rationale for separating the functional units like this. I know this is all *far* simpler with separate apps, but that's not ideal for us.

Comment: Sure. Just use the same DB.

Comment: That seems like a simple answer. But what about migrations? How does migrating the customer models affect work orders?

Comment: You could use a reusable app to define all of the models, and include it in each site. If it’s in `sys.path`, you only need 1 copy, which should house all of its own migrations.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having multiple sites?

Comment: Why do you want multiple sites?

Answer (score 0):

I currently work on something similar. Our Django project includes 3 apps. The models are stored in their appropriate apps but are shared amongst them when necessary (importing).

We have three live sites which are run by the three apps.

```
___.something.com
___2.something.com
___3.something.com
```

I don't know how this would work if you had three projects for the three sites. You would have to make sure that the models and migrations were always in sync. This would become very impractical.

This is why Django has apps in the first place. So incase you need to scale or branch out, you can do it in the same project.

Comment: Right - and I actually have a separate project with the same setup you describe. Two separate domains, all under a single Django application but with different `settings.py` files (with a shared base). I'm just trying to figure out of further separation is possible beyond just the app level. I read somewhere that the example on the official Django documentation about `sites` is actually two separate Django projects, not just various apps within one project. That's what got me thinking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware). It's definitely possible to do what you're describing.

Benefits are:

1. You would have one database that is accessible from all three domain names.
2. Django can tailor the templates/data presented to the user based on the subdomain.
3. You can do this all with one server...just use virtual hosts on your NGINX or Apache server.

Comment: Yeah, I got it all up and running and it's working great. Two different domains, very different experiences/purposes, one database for them both.